# JavaScript dialog return

Tags: javascript, function, return-value, extendscript, adobe-scriptui

I've got a JavaScript function that draws a dialog. I'd like to have it return the value the user specifies.  The problem is, the dialog is closed when a user clicks on of two buttons, which have `onClick` events assigned to them.  The only way I know to grab these events is by assigning functions to them, which means that a return causes the assigned function to return, and not my inputDialog function.  I'm sure I'm just doing this in a stupid way.

In case you're wondering, this script is using Adobe's ExtendScript API for extending After Effects.

Here's the code:

```
function inputDialog (queryString, title){
    // Create a window of type dialog.
    var dia = new Window("dialog", title, [100,100,330,200]);  // bounds = [left, top, right, bottom]
    this.windowRef = dia;

    // Add the components, a label, two buttons and input
    dia.label = dia.add("statictext", [20, 10, 210, 30]);
    dia.label.text = queryString;
    dia.input = dia.add("edittext", [20, 30, 210, 50]);
    dia.input.textselection = "New Selection";
    dia.input.active = true;
    dia.okBtn = dia.add("button", [20,65,105,85], "OK");
    dia.cancelBtn = dia.add("button", [120, 65, 210, 85], "Cancel");


    // Register event listeners that define the button behavior

    //user clicked OK
    dia.okBtn.onClick = function() {
        if(dia.input.text != "") { //check that the text input wasn't empty
            var result = dia.input.text;
            dia.close(); //close the window
            if(debug) alert(result);
            return result;
        } else { //the text box is blank
            alert("Please enter a value."); //don't close the window, ask the user to enter something
        }
    };

    //user clicked Cancel
    dia.cancelBtn.onClick = function() {
        dia.close();
        if(debug) alert("dialog cancelled");
        return false;
    };

    // Display the window
    dia.show();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a solution.  It's really ugly, but it'll tide me over for now...  Anyone have a better solution?

```
    var ret = null;

    // Register event listeners that define the button behavior
    dia.okBtn.onClick = function() {
        if(dia.input.text != "") { //check that the text input wasn't empty
            var result = dia.input.text;
            dia.close(); //close the window
            if(debug) alert(result);
            ret = result;
            return result;
        } else { //the text box is blank
            alert("Please enter a value."); //don't close the window, ask the user to enter something
        }
    };

    dia.cancelBtn.onClick = function() { //user cancelled action
        dia.close();
        ret = false;
        return false;
    };

    // Display the window
    dia.show();

    while(ret == null){};
    return ret;
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be slightly better to close the dialog with a specific integer. You can then check the return value from `show()` and return the appropriate value. See jongware's reference to [ExtendScript ScriptUI Window's close method](http://jongware.mit.edu/Sui/pc_Window.html#close).

```
// Register event listeners that define the button behavior
dia.okBtn.onClick = function() {
    if(dia.input.text != "") { //check that the text input wasn't empty
        dia.close(1); //close the window
    } else { //the text box is blank
        alert("Please enter a value."); //don't close the window, ask the user to enter something
    }
};

dia.cancelBtn.onClick = function() { //user cancelled action
    dia.close(2);
};


var buttonCloseValue = dia.show(); //blocks until user interaction
if(dia.show() == 1) {
    if(debug) alert(dia.input.text);
    return dia.input.text;
}
return false;
```